# Combine PDF files with ghostscript ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ghostscript

In my rails application I need to combine multiple PDF documents.
For merging PDFs I currently use the '[combine_pdf](https://github.com/boazsegev/combine_pdf)' gem and so far, it did a great job.

Unfortunately, combine_pdf sometimes throws errors while merging certain documents. So I want to implement a fallback in case of combine_pdf is not able to merge the documents.

Now I'm thinking about using ghostscript to combine pdf documents.

`gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress -sOutputFile=#{output_path} #{input1_path} #{input2_path}`

Is it possible to execute this command with a ghostscript wrapper for ruby like [RGhost](https://github.com/shairontoledo/rghost)?

Answer (score 0):

Ghostscript doesn't 'combine' PDF files. It creates a new PDF file which should be visually identical with the input. Please have a read [here](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.22/VectorDevices.htm#Overview) to get an explanation. You need to be aware that some non-marking content may be lost, and the structure of the final file will be markedly different to the input files.

I'd have thought the simplest solution was just to fork a process.